# Clickonce publish - "The file 'default.htm' already exists in this Web site"

Tags: .net, deployment, permissions, clickonce

When I try to (re)publish my clickonce app, I am getting this:

Failed to copy file 'E:*path*\default.htm' to '\*path*\default.htm'. Unable to add 'default.htm' to the Web site.  The file 'default.htm' already exists in this Web site.

There are three files with the same error message - default.htm, setup.exe and my app's .application file.

What's going on?  I've published this before, many times - although it's been a few months since the last publish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might wanna post this on UserVoice (cause its going to get into server details quickly) but it seems to me that the file already exists.  2 most obvious possibilities are:

1) The web server has set the file to read-only.

2) I think ClickOnce uses a different directory per deployment.  Did you remember to bump the version number up?

Comment: It was a permissions problem on the server.  Thanks!